# Multiple tags / folders in Google Reader

Tags: iphone, google-reader

I want to be able to grab data from multiple tags / folders in a users Google Reader.

I know how to do one `http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/label/SOMELABEL` but how would you do two or three or ten?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can get multiple tags/folders in one request. If it's feasible you should iterate over the different tags/folders and aggregate them in your application.

[edit]
Since it looks like you have a large list of tags/folders you need to query, an alternative is to get the full list of entries, then sort out the ones the user wants. It looks like each entry has a category element that will tell you what tag is associated with it. This might be feasible in your case.

(Source: http://code.google.com/p/pyrfeed/wiki/GoogleReaderAPI)
(Source: http://www.google.com/reader/atom/user/-/state/com.google/starred)

Comment: Yeh Ive considered that, but say a user highlighted 30 folder they wanted to include - I would to make 30 separate calls to Reader API every time... seems total overkill for a simple feature.

Comment: Revised my answer to include a possible alternative for you.

Comment: Hey thats it I think as I get all the data anyway - so I should filter the data once its downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot get aggregated data as you hope to be able to. If you think about it, even Google lets you browse folders or tags one at a time, and do not aggregate a sub-set of them.

You can choose to have a list of all the items (for each one of their available statuses) or a list of a particular tag/folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in 2 requests. First you need to perform a `GET` request to `http://www.google.com/reader/stream/items/ids`. It supports several parameters like

- `s` (required parameter; stream id to fetch; may be defined more than one time),
- `n` (required; number of items to fetch)
- `r` for ranking (optional)
- and others (see [more](http://undoc.in/googlereader.html) under `/ids` section)

And then you should perform a `POST` request (this is because there could be a lot of ids, and therefore the request could be cut off) to `http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/stream/items/contents`. The required parameter is `i` which holds the feed item identifier (could be defined more than once).

This should return data from several feeds (as returned for me).